# How do I INSERT into a mysql database using data obtained through a SELECT query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Using node.js and the mysql module, I am trying to select data from a table, manipulate that data, then insert the manipulate data to another table in the database.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'username',
password: 'pass',
database: 'db',
});

var q = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
var data_wanted = [];

connection.query(q, function(err, result) {

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {     //let's say there are 100 rows in table1
        var manipulated_data = result + 1;
        data_wanted.push(manipulated_data);
    }

});
```

Ideally, I would take the values in data_wanted and bulk insert it. Something like:

```
var q2 = 'INSERT into table2 (number) VALUES ?';

connection.query(q2, [data_wanted], function(err, result) {
    //bulk inserts data_wanted[]
});
```

However, data_wanted does not take data from the first query.

```
console.log(data_wanted) //outputs []; still empty, even after 1st query
```

I believe that this is a scope issue. But I have no idea how to actually solve this problem. I would appreciate help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this

```node
var q2 = 'INSERT into table2 (number) VALUES (?)';
```

I think its just the brackets you were missing.

You are using statements so you will have to add more code of course.

I hope I helped.

Comment: My problem is that is that the data I tried extract from the first query (a SELECT query) is, in fact, not extracted. I have no data to insert in the first place, so I don't believe the INSERT query is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one query insert all.
This a example:

```
INSERT INTO users_log (`name`,`address`)
SELECT u.`name`,u.`address`
FROM users u ;
```

Table users:
[image]

Table users_log:

[image]

This link documment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I can't use INSERT SELECTs because, in reality, I want to manipulate selected data with complex conditionals. The result+1 is really just an example.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause because your code doesn't have connect to database .You must to connect database before when you do query sql. You can refer this way.

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'db',
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
    });

    var q = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
    var data_wanted = [];

    connection.query(q, function(err, result) {
        result.forEach(function(row) {
           console.log(row);
          data_wanted.push(row);
        });
       console.log(data_wanted);
    });
```

Comment: I can most definitely access the data within connection.query() so it's definitely connected to my db. But I tried adding what you said anyway, and sadly it didn't work :(    My problem is definitely with scope. Adding onto  data_wanted[] inside the anonymous function within the .query parameters does not work. The array gets thrown out. No idea how to do it otherwise, though.

Comment: @ssor  I edited your code. the cause is async nodejs. you can put console.log(data_wanted); inside connection.query method . it will show result

Comment: The point is that I want data_wanted[] outside the query. I'm pushing the results of connection.query into data_wanted[] so I could take that data and manipulate it outside the connection.query method. Inside .query, data_wanted[] successfully gets filled, but outside .query, data_wanted[] is empty.

Comment: @ssor you must to research async/await to undertand about it.